# Est-ce juste d'utiliser une préposition à la fin d'une phrase?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, prépositions

J'ai entendu quelqu'un qui disait: *"C'est un projet intéressant qu'on travaille sur"*. Pour moi, l'expression n'est pas lourde quand on vient de l'entendre, mais est-ce qu'elle est juste, grammaticalement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cette préposition n'est pas sans complément. Le complément est « un projet », lié par « que ». Donc la question est si une préposition peut s'employer à la fin d'une phrase.

En français dit « standard », **non**, ce n'est pas possible. On dira plutôt :

> C'est un projet intéressant sur lequel on travaille.

Cela dit, il y a peut-être des variantes régionales où on peut parler ainsi. Par exemple, ici au Canada, j'ai des élèves en immersion française qui préfèrent des formulations comme « J'ai trouvé un ami pour jouer avec. » Ce phénomène est si répandu que je commence à me demander si c'est un régionalisme. Sinon à ce moment, chez la prochaine génération peut-être ! Mais quand j'en parle avec des linguistes, ils affirment d'une certitude presque suspecte que cette tournure n'existe pas.

Comment: On ne dit pas du tout cela en français, on ne dit que « C'est un projet intéressant sur lequel on travaille. », strictement. Le rejet de la préposition à la fin de la phrase est typique de l'allemand et de l'anglais et n'existe pas en français. Cela ne veut pas dire qu'il ne puisse pas y être introduit mais ce n'est pas ce qui est discuté. Il y a en en France, cependant, la tendance de ce rejet pour la préposition « avec »https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pour+jouer+avec.&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpour%20jouer%20avec%20.%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=travaille+sur.&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: C'est amusant, en Belgique, le *avec* est utilisé d'une manière comparable à celle citée pour le québec, mais par influence du néerlandais. On peut entendre par exemple "je viens avec", calqué sur "ik kom mee" en néerlandais.

Comment: Dans le même style que "venir/jouer/tenir avec", on dit aussi parfois : "voter pour", "être contre" ou (plus familièrement) "sortir avec", mais c'est plutôt une omission du nom/pronom qu'un rejet de la préposition en fin de phrase.

Comment: Remarque ngram : Curieusement (ou pas) il y a plus de voter contre que de voter pour https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=voter+pour.+%2C+voter+contre.&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvoter%20pour%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvoter%20contre%20.%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @radouxju : Normal! On n'a qqchose à dire que quand on est contre! ;-) Cela dit, dans tes exemples précis *pour* et *contre* sont des adverbes. Et pour un adverbe, la position est OK.

Comment: De même que dans les exemples ci-dessus, dans ton exemple *un ami pour jouer avec*, *avec* est utilisé en tant qu'adverbe. Et là encore, pour un adverbe, sa position est OK.

Comment: En + de ce qui précède, on observera que la plupart des prépositions proviennent... d'anciens **adverbes**. Nombreuses sont celles qui ont gardé la possibilité de cet emploi adverbial. (Cela ne vaut effectivement pas pour *sur*)

Comment: @aCOSwt merci pour ces précisions. Je pense que nous sommes d'accord de dire que l'emploi adverbial est accepté et que la construction est donc correcte. Ce que je voulais dire, c'est que si l'utilisation adverbiale de certaines prépositions est acceptée, ce n'est pas le cas du rejet en fin de phrase (qui n'est jamais accepté à ma connaissance). Dire "Je joue avec (cela)" est correct, mais dire "L'objet que je joue avec." n'est pas correct.

Comment: Merci à toute personne a participé dans cette discussion, qui était trop riche

Comment: @Luke: « jouer avec » n'est pas du tout un régionalisme, c'est du français habituel. Explications dans les autres commentaires.

Comment: Le gros problème de "qu'on travaille sur" est l'utilisation absolue/adverbiale de *sur* qui semble généralement être une forme clitique qui ne peut pas se retrouver sous l'accent en fin de phrase. Le pendant accentué de *sur* est *dessus* et de fait une structure comme "Un projet qu'on travaille dessus", bien que tout aussi non standard, est occasionnellement utilisée

Comment: @Eauquidort True, and similar for *dedans*, etc. Interestingly, *dehors* ne gêne pas dans cette position.